# Text Field Disappears in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a main view controller in the storyboard and added a login form with a simple button. The login is composed of two text fields

[image: Login]

However when I run the application in the IOS simulator, all I get is this!

[image]

What happened to my password field? What reasons could there be for it not showing? This is my very first iphone app btw. Its Xcode 4.6 and IOS 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your 2 textfields have a vertical constraint to the top edge. The password textfield should be hidden under the login button.

You can play around with your constraints, or maybe have the Login button constrain to the top edge as well.

Edit:

Auto Layout

[image]

No autolayout

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have Xcode 5, but I was able to fix the problem by changing to 3.5 inch form factor. Thanks